# Access custom Java Object from JSF XHTML file

Tags: java, jsf

I have created a simple XHTML file and a corresponding Java Bean. Inside the Java Bean, I generate an ArrayList with objects of my custom class "FilePreview", which is defined in a different package (I imported it into the Bean, of course). In my XHTML-File I use ui-repeat to iterate over the list and display each element. I try to access the properties of my objects using get-Methods.

My XHTML-File

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>        
        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </h:head>
    <body>
        <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="title">
                Dateien
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">
                <b:container>
                                <ui:repeat value="#{FileBean.files}" var="files">
                                    <b:panel title="#{files.headline}" look="primary">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{files.description}" />
                                    </b:panel>
                                    <b:alert class= "file" severity="success"><strong>#{files.headline}</strong><br></br> <span>#{files.description}</span></b:alert>
                                </ui:repeat>                              
                </b:container>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaBean:

```
import de.unibremen.st.gradelog.model.FilePreview;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@ManagedBean(name = "FileBean")
@SessionScoped
public class FileBean implements Serializable {
    // private DBHandler handler;
    private ArrayList<FilePreview> files;

    public void create() {
        files = new ArrayList();
        files.add(new FilePreview("Hausordnung",
                "Anbei findet Ihr die aktualisierte Hausordnung. Bitte gründlich lesen!",
                null, null, null));
       }

    public ArrayList getFiles() {
        /**
         * DBHandler.getFiles(userID);
         */
        System.out.println("Lese die Dateien aus.");
        create();
        return files;
    }

}
```

And finally, the class FilePreview:

```
package de.unibremen.st.gradelog.model.FilePreview
public class FilePreview {
    private String headline, description, authorID, fileID;
    private File file;

    public FilePreview(String headline, String description, String authorID,
            String fileID, File file) {
        this.headline = headline;
        this.description = description;
        this.authorID = authorID;
        this.fileID = fileID;
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

   //... more simple getters and setters
}
```

Everything seems to work just find, but when I run the application and access my new page, I get the following error:

```
Schwerwiegend:   Error Rendering View[/files.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /files.xhtml @51,82 value="#{FileBean.files}": java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/unibremen/st/gradelog/model/FilePreview
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:279)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:255)
...
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/unibremen/st/gradelog/model/FilePreview
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)
```

Do I have to make the class known to JSF in some way? I'm working with an existing JSF project, and when I tried to do the same thing with a new project, everything worked just fine.

Anyone got an idea what could cause this?

Comment: whats going on inside that init() method.. and add the imports please

Comment: If it worked with a new project, maybe try to do a clean and build and restart the server...

Comment: I added some imports. The init() method was meant to be create(), because I did some other (irrelevant) stuff in the init() method and didn't want to bother you with all that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to generate a faces-config.xml file where you declare that your managed bean is FileBean. You have to do something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9igX.png)

Comment: Yes, I did that, and the Bean works just fine. If I return a simple String in the getter, there is no problem, but when I use my custom class things don't work anymore.

Comment: You can´t use ArrayList or List (more general). This doesn't work in Web Java projects. Use Set and in the getter return an iterator. I work like that and it works ok. I don´t know de reason why this doesn´t work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed the type and it works just fine now!

Comment: I´m happy to help.

Comment: No need at all to use a faces-config here instead of annotations... This is not an answer for he actual problem